# Setting end values without animation with AnimatorSet

Tags: android, animation

According to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html#end() end() method should assign the end values for all animations inside the set. However ending does nothing if the set was not started. This is different from ValueAnimator i.e. which does not care and artifically starts the animation, fires onAnimationStart() event and then ends it which results in setting the end values properly.

Let me tell you why this is a problem. If you want to have the ability to update your View with and without animation (depending on the situation) you don't want to have two separate methods for it. Instead you could create an animation and start it normally or immediately set the end values. With ValueAnimator this works nicely. However AnimatorSet does not play ball and if you try to end it before calling start() it simply exits.

One workaround for this is to call start() and end() immediately after but it does not cover the situation with nested AnimatorSets like this:

```
    AnimatorSet mainSet = new AnimatorSet();

    AnimatorSet scaleSet = new AnimatorSet();
    scaleSet.playTogether(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleX", 0.5f),
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "scaleY", 0.5f));

    mainSet.playSequentially(
            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0.5f),
            scaleSet);

    mainSet.start();
    mainSet.end();
```

This causes the mainSet to call end() on all its children. But since AnimatorSet.end() is broken the scaleSet does not set ending values. I attempted to extend AnimatorSet class and fix this but soon found out it is marked final.

In my app I mostly use animations but have some few cases where animations are not needed. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve the proper behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on all child animations with:

```
for (Animator animation : mainSet.getChildAnimations())
{
    animation.start();
    animation.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but a recursive approach can solve this:

```java
    void endAnimationsRecursively(final Animator mainAnimator){
        if (mainAnimator instanceof AnimatorSet) {
            for (final Animator animator : ((AnimatorSet) 
                mainAnimator).getChildAnimations()) {
                endAnimationsRecursively(animator);
            }
            mainAnimator.end();
            mainAnimator.cancel();
        }
    }
```